# Python docstrings and inline code; meaning of the ">>>" syntax

Tags: python, docstring

I have some experience in Python but only recently came across extensive usage of docstrings. I'm going through the [Financial Market Simulator (FMS)](https://pythonhosted.org/fms/) source code, and when I open it in PyCharm I see the following syntax highlighting (screenshot of a code snippet of [one of the modules](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02OIFrBsi3oV2hRdEpYQWtod2s/view?usp=sharing) in FMS):

[image: script-screenshot01]

Why are the statements after the `>>>` highlighted as if they are executable? From what I have read of docstrings, both on the official documentation and on SO (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119308/doctest-for-nested-docstring)) I think that those statements should not execute, but the syntax highlighting is confusing me, leading me to think that the `>>>` is a marker for code within the docstring that one wants executed. Or is this just a PyCharm 'bug'? None of the documentation mentions anything related to this and I'm worried if I'm missing something.

PS: For the record, looking at the code in SublimeText does not reproduce the same behaviour.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**The statements written with `>>>` in the docstrings are [doctests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html).**

It lets you test your code by running examples embedded in the documentation and verifying that they produce the expected results. It parses the help text to find examples, runs them and then compares the output text against the expected value.

**In your case, PyCharm has done the extra task of highlighting the python code in the docstrings. It won't affect your normal function execution so you don't need to worry about it.**

**Example:**
 Lets say I have a script named `doctest_simple_addition` in which i have written some doctests for `add()` function where some test cases gives proper output and some raises an exception. Then i can verify that my function produces the expected results by running those doctests.

**doctest_simple_addition.py**

```
def add(a,b):
    """
    >>> add(1, 2)
    3

    >>> add(5, 3)
    8

    >>> add('a', 1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
    """

    return a + b
```

To run the doctests, use `doctest` as the main program via the `-m` option to the interpreter. Usually, no output is produced while the tests are running. You can add the `-v` option and `doctest` will then print a detailed log of what it’s trying with a summary at the end.

`Doctest` looks for lines beginning with the interpreter prompt, `>>>`, to find the beginning of a test case. The test case is ended by a blank line, or by the next interpreter prompt.

```
$ python -m doctest -v doctest_simple_addition.py 

Trying:
    add(1, 2)
Expecting:
    3
ok
Trying:
    add(5, 3)
Expecting:
    8
ok
Trying:
    add('a', 1)
Expecting:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
ok
1 items had no tests:
    doctest_simple_addition
1 items passed all tests:
   3 tests in doctest_simple_addition.add
3 tests in 2 items.
3 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

**Note:** When doctest sees a `traceback` header line (either `Traceback (most recent call last):` or `Traceback (innermost last):`, depending on the version of Python you are running), it skips ahead to find the exception type and message, ignoring the intervening lines entirely.
This is done because paths in a traceback depend on the location where a module is installed on the filesystem on a given system and it would be impossible to write portable tests as the path would change from system to system.

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition is correct, they are to be executed.  But don't worry, they are [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/doctest.html) strings.  They won't interfere with the normal execution of a module, so everything is fine. PyCharm is just being helpful by recognizing them.

Comment: Thanks! So `doctest` runs everything internally after the `>>>` and compares the output with the expected output given in turn on the line immediately below? Also, in the example I provided, are `Traceback ...` and `MissingParameter..` function calls that are actually executed, or just some text printed to screen as a message when the test fails?

Comment: @avg You're welcome! Yes, exactly, everything following the `>>>` line is the expected output. `Traceback` and `MissingParameter` are just part of the output, the traceback in this case. At the beginning, you have the traceback header and at the end the exception type at the last line. In case of exceptions, everything in between those two lines is ignored.

Comment: I was going to accept your answer, but @rahul wrote one that is more complete so I'm going to accept his. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you are seeing is part of the testing support for Python available in Pycharm.

The settings option is called "Analyze Python code in docstrings" and is available under [Python Integrated Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/python-integrated-tools.html):

> If this check box is selected, PyCharm highlights the code example and
>   performs syntax checks and code inspections. If this check box is not
>   selected, the code fragments inside docstrings are not analyzed.

You can disable it if you prefer.

The online documentation details how to [run tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/running-tests.html) and [view their results](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/viewing-and-exploring-test-results.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have only recently started using PyCharm and this is very helpful.